# Convert integers to "/ \ " strings

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm trying convert integer number to string build from "/" or "\"

For example: 6 = `/\`, 22 = `//\\\\`
 ,where   /=1   \=5

For x=1 or x=5 is correct

```
    public String fromArabic(int x)
    {
        if(x>29 || x<1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error IllegalArgumentException");

        int tmp=x;
        String out="";
        StringBuilder o=new StringBuilder(out);

        while(tmp!=0)
        {
            if(tmp-5>=0)
            {
                tmp-=5;
                o.append("\\");
            }
            else if(tmp-1>=0 && tmp-5<0)
            {
                tmp-=1;
                o.append("/");
            }
        }

       out=o.toString();
       return out;
    }
```

OUTPUT:

> expected:<[//\\]> but was:<[\\//]>

How to make it correct?

Comment: Why `22 == //\\ `, please? `5 + 5 + 1 + 1 == 12`, not `22`?

Comment: //\\ (12) - 1 + 1 + 5 + 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String fromArabic(int x)
{
    if(x>29 || x<1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int tmp = x;
    StringBuilder o = new StringBuilder();
    while(tmp != 0)
    {
        if(tmp >= 5)
        {
            tmp -= 5;
            o.append("\\");
        }
        else if(tmp >= 1)
        {
            tmp-=1;
            o.append("/");
        }
    }
   return o.reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to loop until tmp == 0 and each iteration substract 5 or 1.
if you assign `x / 5` to an int you get the number of `'\'` symbols,
and `x % 5` gives you number of `'/'` symbols

Here it is in one line (Java 8)

```
return String.join("", Collections.nCopies((x%5), "/"), Collections.nCopies((x/5), "\\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reverse the if sequence inside while:

```
while(tmp!=0)
{
  if  (tmp-1>=0 && tmp-5<0)
  {
    tmp-=1;
    o.append("/");
  }
  else if(tmp-5>=0)
  {                
    tmp-=5;
     o.append("\\");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest building the string in two stages:

1. Add all 1-s
2. Add all 5-s

Technically all we want is `x % 5` `/` characters followed by  `x / 5` `\` ones.

Something like this (if we want to spare loops and `StringBuilder`):

```
  // static: we don't want "this" in the context
  public static String fromArabic(int x) {
    if (x > 29 || x < 1)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error IllegalArgumentException");

    // Let's preserve StringBuilder and the loop(s)
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < x % 5; ++i)
      sb.append('/');

    for (int i = 0; i < x / 5; ++i)
      sb.append('\\');

    return sb.toString(); 
  }
```

A shorter code is to build the string directly:

```
  public static String fromArabic(int x) {
      if (x > 29 || x < 1)
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error IllegalArgumentException");

      char[] chars = new char[x % 5 + x / 5];
      Arrays.fill(chars, 0, x % 5, '/');    // Ones
      Arrays.fill(chars, x / 5, '\\');      // Fives

      return new String(chars);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static String fromArabic(int x) {
    if(x > 29 || x < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error IllegalArgumentException");

    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder("");

    int countOf1 = x % 5;
    int countOf5  = x / 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < countOf1; i++) {
        out.append("/");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < countOf5; i++) {
        out.append("\\");
    }

    return out.toString();
}
```